# How to combine AccounId and the time stamp to create a new key for Storage map in Substrate

Tags: rust, substrate

I am trying to create a new Key to store data in to a `StorageMap` by combining the account ID and the time stamp

Im not sure how to get a string representation of the account and concatenate the timestamp

```
let origin_account = ensure_signed(origin);
let time = <pallet_timestamp::Module<T>>::get();
```

Comment: does `format!()` not work? what have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you want to use one of two things:

1. Use a tuple to represent both pieces of information as a single key:

```
/// Any signal messages waiting to be sent.
#[pallet::storage]
pub(super) type MyMap<T: Config> = StorageMap<
    _,
    Blake2_128Concat,
    (T::AccountId, T::Moment), // <--- key will be a tuple of the two data
    ValueType,
>;
```

and

```
let origin_account = ensure_signed(origin)?;
let time = <pallet_timestamp::Module<T>>::get();
let value = 99;
MyMap::<T>::insert((origin_account, time), value);
```

2. Or you want to use a double map, which explicitly supports two keys.

```
#[pallet::storage]
pub(super) type MyDoubleMap<T: Config> = StorageDoubleMap<
    _,
    Blake2_128Concat,
    T::AccountId, // <-- key 1
    Blake2_128Concat,
    T::Moment, // <-- key 2
    ValueType,
>;
```

and

```
let origin_account = ensure_signed(origin)?;
let time = <pallet_timestamp::Module<T>>::get();
let value = 99;
MyDoubleMap::<T>::insert(origin_account, time, value);
```